# cant use primefaces xmlns

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm currently learning to develop a JSF 2 application with Primefaces
I have imported both JSF and Primefaces dependencies using maven:

```
<!-- Implementação do Java Server Faces 2 (MOJARRA) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Implementação do PrimeFaces 6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

But I can't use the primefaces with xmlns="http://primefaces.org/ui" in my .xhtml files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Nome"/>
            <h:inputText/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also when I run the application, using Tomcat 7.0 server, I can't access it using localhost:8080/projectname/pagename.xhtml

How can I fix this?

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>algo.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <display-name>opn</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I can't see where you include the primefaces namespace try this xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"

Comment: with jsf 2.3 there is no need to put all jsf things in the web.xml. 2.3.4 is btw out as is PrimeFaces 6.2. And please use jsf 2.2/2.3 namespaces

Comment: @Ovoxo sorry, I forgot to add that I tried adding the xmlns exactly like that, rebuilt the project, cleaned it, cleaned the server and even restarted eclipse but still nothing changed

Comment: @Kukeltje so you are saying that I don't need to add primefaces when I use JSF 2.2 or higher?

Comment: No, I mentioned you don't have to add everything in web.xml for jsf 2.2 or higher (if you want to use the defaults what most people want). Adding PrimeFaces in as a library is ofcourse a good thing to do as is adding omnifaces and optimusfaces